# Lorentzian Einstein metric where $R_{ij} = g_{ij}$?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, cosmological-constant

Does there exist a Lorentzian metric $g_{ij}$ (with signature $-,+,+,+$) which also satisfy that $g_{ij}=R_{ij}$ (e.g. is Einstein with $k=1$)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. In fact, there are many. Any vacuum solutions to Einstein's equation with positive [cosmological constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant) would be an example, with the most well-known one being [de Sitter space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Sitter_space).

Note that scaling $k$ doesn't matter, since if you rescale the metric, the curvature scales differently and so you can always arrange for $k = 1$.